# Azure mobile service : send push notification to specific android device

Tags: java, android, push-notification, registration, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to use Azure mobile services to send push notifications. I got it working but currently it sends to all devices that use the application key. I realise that in the gcm.push.send() function I have to give a tag instead of null if i want to send it to individuals or groups.

I want to send it only to the current user. The user who calls the insert. I tried putting in the users gcm registration id but this does not work.

I saw examples of people registering their tags like this (in push->edit script):

```
exports.register = function (registration, registrationContext, done) {

var userId = registrationContext.user.userId;  

   registration.tags.push(userId);

done();
};
```

However im not using authentication so my `user` variable is undefined. All ive got is a unique identifier in my item table (item.id) and the registration id (item.regid). **How can I get my tag working?** This is my insert :

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
console.log("Registration ID -> " + item.regid);
var payload = {
    "data": {
          "message": "notification added"
         }
};  

request.execute({
success: function() {
    // If the insert succeeds, send a notification.
    push.gcm.send(item.regid, payload, {
        success: function(pushResponse) {
            console.log("Sent push:", pushResponse, payload);
            request.respond();
            },              
        error: function (pushResponse) {
            console.log("Error Sending push:", pushResponse);
            request.respond(500, { error: pushResponse });
            }
        });
    },
error: function(err) {
    console.log("request.execute error", err)
    request.respond();
}
}); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notification Hubs does not have the ability to send to a specific device right now.

The mechanism for simulate this is through the registration process and tags.   Use the Notification Hubs API directly.  When you register a device, register to listen with a tag that is appropriate to the device or user.  For example, register to listen to tags USER-userid and DEVICE-deviceid.

Then, when you want to send to a specific device, send to DEVICE-deviceid and if you want to send to all devices that are registered to a specific user, you can send to USER-userid; obviously, replace the userid and deviceid with the appropriate values.

You can find out more about tags here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn530749.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send notification to specific user you must register them with unique tag or unique identifier as Adrian hall in previous answer described,I agree with him.As unique identifier in Android you can use DeviceId and in Ios identifierForVendor they are unique and they never change.